# How to pass PHP 2d array to JS script?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Let's say I have a table

```
[table fruits]
--------+------------+
ID [PK] | fruit      |
--------+------------+
1       | Orange     |
2       | Banana     |
3       | Coconut    |
```

and I need to save a list of IDs and names in a JS array, like for example:

```
var fkOptionList = [[1]['Orange'],[2]['Banana'],[3]['Coconut']]
```

in PHP I achieved this by:

```
        $fkOptionTableR = $fkOptionTableQ->result_array();

        $fkOption2dArray[] = array();
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        foreach ($fkOptionTableR as $array) {
          foreach ($array as $row) {
          $fkOption2dArray[$i][$j] = $row;
            $j++;
          }
          $i++;
          $j = 0;
        }
```

which results in (according to `var_dump`):

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(6) "Orange" } 
[1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(6) "Banana" } 
[2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(7) "Coconut" } 
}
```

I would need that array in my JS script, but the problem is it's in other file (above PHP script is loaded once by a CI's controller). Is there a way to pass it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Your `fkOptionList` is a syntax error.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - right, it meant to be `fkOptionList = [[1, 'Orange'],[2, 'Banana'],[3, 'Coconut']]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In PHP**

```
$yourArray = json_encode($fkOptionTableR);
```

**In JAVASCRIPT**

```
var twoDarray = <?php echo $yourArray ?>
```

Comment: the second doesn't work (`unexpected <`), anyway I have my json_encoded array in a div, but don't know how can I paste its content to a JS variable body so that it will become an array?

Comment: use var array =  $("#That Div Id").text();

Comment: I've tried, it treats `var array` like a string then, not as an array

Comment: when I use `alert(fkOptionList[1]);` it returns `[` instead of array's element

Comment: I've made a workaround, creating JS var in PHP script, instead of echoing it in a div. Thanks for help.